# How do I enable the check box again?

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA code which checks the value of a cell and should enable/disable a checkbox depending on the value:

```vb
Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()
    If Range("A4").Value = "ZJ3" Then
        CheckBox2.Enabled = True
    ElseIf Range("A4").Value = "ZJ2" Then
        CheckBox2.Enabled = False
        CheckBox2.Value = False
    
    End If
End Sub
```

When I select ZJ2 in cell A4, the checkbox does what is intended, and disables the value and the entry of the checkbox.

When I change the value of ZJ3 it remains greyed out when it should enable.

Comment: What value do you see when debugging the code?

Comment: Isn't the issue that you can't use the checkbox to enable itself if it's currently disabled?

Comment: The issue is that when I change the value of the cell to ZJ3, it should re enable, however it remains greyed out

Comment: If I'm understanding your situation, no - you can't use a disabled checkbox to re-enable itself. You need something else to re-enable it. Perhaps the `Worksheet_Change` event is better here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be better to use the `Worksheet_Change` event to control whether the checkbox is enabled or not, something like the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A4")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Select Case Me.Range("A4").Value
        Case "ZJ3"
            Me.CheckBox2.Enabled = True
        Case "ZJ2"
            Me.CheckBox2.Enabled = False
            Me.CheckBox2.Value = False
    End Select
End Sub
```